# How to add checkbox and make some function running

Tags: php, wordpress

Could you help to add checkbox inside publish post in wordpress and if checkbox is checked some function will be running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save a checkbox meta box in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526374/how-to-save-a-checkbox-meta-box-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this code

```
add_action('post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'createCustomField');

add_action('save_post', 'saveCustomField');

function createCustomField()
{
    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    if (get_post_type($post_id) != 'post') {
        return;
    }

    $value = get_post_meta($post_id, '_my_custom_field', true);
    wp_nonce_field('my_custom_nonce_'.$post_id, 'my_custom_nonce');
    ?>
    <div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last">
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked($value, true, true); ?> name="_my_custom_field" /><?php _e('My Custom Checkbox Field', 'pmg'); ?></label>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function saveCustomField($post_id)
{
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return;
    }

    if (
        !isset($_POST['my_custom_nonce']) ||
        !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['my_custom_nonce'], 'my_custom_nonce_'.$post_id)
    ) {
        return;
    }

    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['_my_custom_field'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_my_custom_field', $_POST['_my_custom_field']);
    } else {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, '_my_custom_field');
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: sry cant add Vote for feedback coz new member :D